# Mac OS install ionic cli

Tags: ionic-framework, apple-m1

Unable to install ionic on M1 mac mini (see terminal output below)

timothy@Timothys-Mac-mini ~ % sudo npm i -g @ionic/cli
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: 
npm WARN deprecated superagent@5.3.1: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases.

changed 218 packages, and audited 219 packages in 2s

26 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
timothy@Timothys-Mac-mini ~ % ionic -v
zsh: command not found: ionic
timothy@Timothys-Mac-mini ~ %